# Another problem with unload function, node set to null is repopulating somehow

Tags: c, cs50

I'm making a function to free a hash table from memory. At the moment, I'm only attempting to set the nodes to NULL to make sure that it's iterating correctly. But I'm getting output that I don't understand.

This is my current hash table:

[image]

This is my current output. It's an infinite loop:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
bool unload(void)
{
    // For all elements in the hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        // Until break...
        while (1)
        {
            // Set traversal node at hash index i, set trailing traversal node to NOLL
            node *curr = table[i];
            printf("start CURR WORD: %s (%p)\n", curr->word, curr); // DEBUG
            node *prev = NULL;

            // If current is NULL, meaning the index head is null, break
            if (curr == NULL)
            {
                printf("CURR is NULL: BREAKING...\n"); // DEBUG
                break;
            }
            
            // if the index head is not NULL, but its' next pointer is NULL, set current to NULL, next iteration
            if (curr->next == NULL)
            {
                printf("HEAD (%s)->Next: NULL, SETTING HEAD TO NULL...\n", curr->word); // DEBUG
                curr = NULL;
                continue;
            }

            // While current is not null, set trailing traversal node to current, set current to its next pointer
            while (curr != NULL)
            {
                printf("CURR is not NULL: (%s), NEXT...\n", curr->word); // DEBUG
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }

            // when current is NUll, set trailing traversal node to NULL
            printf("CURR IS NULL, SETTING PREVIOUS (%s) TO NULL...\n", prev->word);
            prev = NULL;
            printf("PREV WORD: %s\n", prev->word);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The first `if` condition, `if (curr == NULL)`, seems to be triggering just fine. `table[0]` is `NULL`, so it breaks the first iteration of `while (1)`. What the rest is doing, I don't understand. As intended, it will skip the first two nodes, landing on `NULL`. Then, apparently, it will set the previous node to `NULL`, like it's supposed to. But in the next iteration of `while (1)`, the node that it was supposed to have set to `NULL` is still populated, despite the command `prev = NULL;`, and despite the two print statements before and after that command (`printf("CURR IS NULL, SETTING PREVIOUS (%s) TO NULL...\n", prev->word);` and `printf("PREV WORD: %s\n", prev->word);`) triggering as well.

Can someone tell me what's going wrong here? Why is the node that's being set to NULL repopulating on the next iteration? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is what I'm trying to achieve...

`LIST 00: { } LIST 01: {NODE 1, NODE 2, }`

```
UNTIL THE HEAD IS NULL
    IF the head is NULL
        BREAK

    IF the head is not NULL, but its NEXT pointer is NULL
        Set head to NULL
        next iteration

    IF neither the head nor its next pointer are NULL
        Move to the next node until you reach NULL

    IF the current node is NULL
        Set the previous node to NULL
```

In List 00, the first `IF` is met, and it breaks.
In List 01, the third `IF` is met, and it moves until `NULL`. Then the fourth `IF` is met, and the node before it should be set to `NULL`. At the beginning of iteration 2, it should look like this:

`LIST 00: { } LIST 01: {NODE 1, }`

In which case, the second `IF` is met. It should set the head to `NULL`, and move on to the next iteration:

`LIST 00: { } LIST 01: { }`

Now, the first `IF` is met, so it should break the `while (1)` loop and move on to the next iteration in the `for` loop.

Comment: `curr` is always reset at the top of the while loop and `i` is never incremented. This is causing the infinite loop.

Comment: @Mike67 I don't understand. curr is supposed to be reset at the top, because it needs to traverse the list again to find the next null position. i should iterate in the for loop. The while loop should only iterate until curr is null, and it should get one step closer to null with each iteration, because prev is set to null once curr reaches null.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is caused by the `while(1)` loop. At the top, `curr` is set to `table[i]`. In the loop, curr is set to null, but that does not matter because the `break` statement is never hit and curr is reset to the same value at the top of the loop.

I commented the code to help explain the flow:

```
bool unload(void)
{
    // For all elements in the hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        // Until break...
        while (1)
        {
            // Set traversal node at hash index i, set trailing traversal node to NOLL
            node *curr = table[i];  // <<<<<<< curr set to same value, curr in NOT null, and i is the same as last loop
            printf("start CURR WORD: %s (%p)\n", curr->word, curr); // DEBUG
            node *prev = NULL;

            // If current is NULL, meaning the index head is null, break
            if (curr == NULL)  // <<<<<<<<<<<< skip this, curr is NOT null
            {
                printf("CURR is NULL: BREAKING...\n"); // DEBUG
                break;  // <<<< never gets here
            }
            
            // if the index head is not NULL, but its' next pointer is NULL, set current to NULL, next iteration
            if (curr->next == NULL)  // <<<<<<<<<  skip this, next is NOT null
            {
                printf("HEAD (%s)->Next: NULL, SETTING HEAD TO NULL...\n", curr->word); // DEBUG
                curr = NULL;
                continue;
            }

            // While current is not null, set trailing traversal node to current, set current to its next pointer
            while (curr != NULL)  //  <<<<<<<<<< move curr forward until curr = null
            {
                printf("CURR is not NULL: (%s), NEXT...\n", curr->word); // DEBUG
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
             
            //   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   at this point, curr = null

            // when current is NUll, set trailing traversal node to NULL
            printf("CURR IS NULL, SETTING PREVIOUS (%s) TO NULL...\n", prev->word);  // <<<< no curr change
            prev = NULL;                                                             // <<<< no curr change
            printf("PREV WORD: %s\n", prev->word);                                   // <<<< no curr change
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

------- UPDATE -------

Based on the updated post, this code should achieve the correct result:

```
bool unload(void)
{
    // For all elements in the hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        node *curr = table[i];  // set head
        if (curr == NULL)  continue;  // skip, go to next head
        curr = curr->next; // top of linked list
        
        // set linked list elements to null
        while (curr != NULL) 
        {
            printf("CURR is not NULL: (%s), NEXT...\n", curr->word);
            node *prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next
            printf("SETTING PREVIOUS (%s) TO NULL...\n", prev->word);
            prev = NULL;
            printf("PREV WORD: %s\n", prev->word);
        } // while curr
    } // for i  
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. But it isn't `curr` that should change until the head is the only node left, and therefore `curr` is the only pointer to change to `NULL`. Until then, `curr` only serves as a pointer to discover the next `NULL` position, and `prev` is the pointer that makes the change. Let me see if I can explain what I'm trying to achieve here. See my edit above, please.